# is it possible to be a shader interference with this lightning?

Tags: c++, opengl-es

Im working on Opengl ES I got 2 shader interfering with each other. I mean, if I use the second shader, the lightning shader stops working as it normally does, as if the normals on the vbo gets corrupted. It only happens when I add this shader:

```
    "#ifdef GL_ES                                   \n" //00
"precision mediump float;           \n" //01
"#else                                              \n" //02
"#version   100                                 \n" //03
"precision mediump float;           \n" //04
"#endif 
                                        \n" //05
"//ProgressBarShader\n"
"uniform float iGlobalTime;   \n" //06
"varying vec34 v_position;          \n"
"varying vec2 v_texCoord;           \n" //07
"uniform sampler2D s_texture;   \n" //11

"void main() {\n"                                   //1
" float igt=((iGlobalTime*15.0)+(sin(iGlobalTime)*25.0)); \n"
" if (gl_FragCoord.x>(1024.0-igt)) \n"                                                      
"   gl_FragColor = texture2D( s_texture, v_texCoord ); " 
"}\n";
```

The other one is a Per Fragment Shader took from this web : http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/point-light-per-pixel/
but modified for opengl es 2.0 (and my inputs)

```
    "#ifdef GL_ES                                   \n"
"precision mediump float;           \n"
"#else                                              \n"
"#version   100                                 \n"
"precision mediump float;           \n"
"#endif                                             \n"

"uniform float iGlobalTime;   \n"
"varying vec2 v_texCoord;           \n"
"varying vec4 v_normal;             \n"
"varying vec4 v_position;           \n"

"uniform sampler2D s_texture;   \n"                                                     
"uniform mat4 MVPMat;                   \n"
"uniform mat3 iMVPMat;              \n"
"uniform vec2 iResolution;    \n"
"uniform vec3 iMouse;                   \n"

"uniform vec4  objectMaterialEmission;    // Ecm   \n"
"uniform vec4  objectMaterialAmbient;     // Acm   \n"
"uniform vec4  objectMaterialDiffuse;     // Dcm   \n"
"uniform vec4  objectMaterialSpecular;    // Scm   \n"
"uniform float objectMaterialGlossiness;  // Gcm   \n"
"uniform float objectMaterialShininess;   // Srm   \n"

"uniform float lightStrength; \n"
"uniform vec4    lightAmbient; \n"
"uniform vec4    lightDiffuse; \n"
"uniform vec4    lightSpecular; \n"
"uniform vec3    lightPosition; \n"
"uniform vec3    lightSpotDirection; \n"
"uniform float lightSpotExponent; \n"
"uniform float lightSpotCutoff; // (range: [0.0,90.0], 180.0)\n"
"uniform float lightSpotCosCutoff; // (range: [1.0,0.0],-1.0)\n"
"uniform float lightConstantAttenuation; \n"
"uniform float lightLinearAttenuation; \n"
"uniform float lightQuadraticAttenuation;\n"

"uniform bool lightOn;        \n"

"varying vec3 N;\n"
"varying vec3 v;\n"
"void main (void)  \n"
"{  \n"
"   vec3 L = normalize(-lightPosition.xyz - v);   \n"
"   vec3 E = normalize(-v); // we are in Eye Coordinates, so EyePos is (0,0,0)  \n"
"   vec3 R = normalize(-reflect(L,N));  \n"

"   //calculate Ambient Term:  \n"
"   vec4 Iamb = lightAmbient;    \n"

"   // write Total Color:  \n"
"   vec4 textureColor   =   texture2D( s_texture, v_texCoord );                                                     \n"                                                                                                                 
"       vec4 color              =textureColor;              \n"         

"   //calculate Diffuse Term:  \n"
"   vec4 Idiff = lightDiffuse * max(dot(N,L), 0.0);\n"
"   Idiff = clamp(Idiff, 0.0, 1.0);     \n"


"   float distance      = length(lightPosition-v);                                                                              \n"
"   float attenuation = lightStrength/(lightConstantAttenuation+(distance*lightLinearAttenuation));\n"

"   gl_FragColor = clamp( color *(Idiff+Iamb)*attenuation,0.0,1.0);                                                         \n"
"       gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;"

"}\n";
```

If I use the progress bar shader (the first one), my lightnings dissapears and only some faces gets enlighted. Any other shader works fine, it only gets disrupted when I add the progress bar shader.

I researched the web, but never seen something about shader interfering each other. Is it possible? What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, it was a fail on the data binding, the binding required the shader to be active (glUseProgram) the first time, the binding was correct, but when the lighting shader came, the program active was the wrong one, and the binding when to the other one.

Sorry for the misleading question.

Comment: do I delete the question?